# angular and webapi project structure

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I will be working on angular POC using asp.net webapi.

I want some inputs on setting up the project structure.

We have traditional DAL layer that returns domain classes.

I have created one [DataServices] webapi project having all my webapi controllers and each method makes call to DAL to get data.

Should I put one additional webapi service layer (dataservices.ui) ? Which will internally call the [DataServices] API using httpclient api and convert domain to ui.domain ?

so which one would be advisable

```
UI -> DataServices.UI -> DataServices -> DAL -> DB
```

or

```
UI-> DataServices ->DAL -> DB
```

please advise.  thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Well as you may know AngularJs follows the beautiful pattern of Model View Controller. Thus, this could be recommended that the file structure follows the pattern as well. That is, setting up directories according to subsystems and then generating JS controllers besides HTML templates next to each other with a reasonable name convention, for instance, adding 'Ctrl' stands for controller. 
Moreover, asp.net MVC provides Area registration which undoubtedly emphasizes the concept of SOC (separation of concern); you can take a great advantage of this feature while designing the project structure. As a further point, if you are also applying the two patterns of Unit of work and Repository to handling data layer effectively, you may like to devote a completely separate project to them. 
Anyhow, designing a project as you know is of much more efforts and time but apart from all I've metioned [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826307/AngularJS-With-MVC-Web-API) might give you a big picture. Hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

Why is your DataServices a WebAPI project? are you planning to deploy that on a different server? If so, then going for first options would do (where each component on same server is in save square brackets). I am suggesting a Wrapper just in case you want to keep settings / configuration and some access logic of calling DataServicesWebApi separate from WebAPIUI.

```
[AngularJS -> WebAPIUI -> Wrapper] **->** [DataServicesWebAPI->DAL] **->** [DB]
```

But if you planning of keeping the POC simpler and on same server (and thinking of doing design again for final product) I don't see any need of making multiple layers unless you have some business reasons of having those layers.

```
AngularJS -> WebAPIDataServices -> DAL-> [DB]
```